# Is every element in $SO(2)$ diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

**Is every element in $SO(2)$ diagonalizable in $\mathfrak{so}(2)$?**

I am trying to prove that if $A\in SO(2)$ then $A$ is normal, to do this I need to prove that $AA^*=A^*A$. I know that $AA^T=Id$ and so $AA^*=Id$, but how can I prove that $A^*A=Id$?

On the other hand I also have the following question:

Since $A\in SO(2)$ is normal, $A$ is diagonalizable, that is, $A=PDP^{-1}$ where $D$ is diagonal, can we say that $P\in \mathfrak{so}(2)$? Why?

Comment: You should think through your question as on its false it makes little sense, starting with the title. For instance, the notion of $A^*$ makes sense for matrices with complex coefficients. If you apply it to real matrices, such as elements of $SO(n)$, you obtain $A^*=A^T$ and $AA^T=I=A^TA$, hence, $A$ is automatically normal. Is this all what you wanted to know? As for the title question, what do you mean for elements of a Lie group $G$ to be diagonalizable "in its Lie algebra"? Do you mean the adjoint representation of $G$ consists of diagonalizable matrices? ...

Comment: If so, $SO(2)$ has trivial adjoint representation, hence, every element will be trivially diagonalizable (since it is already diagonal, the identity matrix).

Comment: @MoisheKohan 
So we always have to if $A\in SO(2)$ then $A=PDP^{-1}$ where $P\in \mathfrak{so}(2)$ and $D$ is diagonal?

Comment: Over reals, elements of $SO(2)$ are not diagonalizable (unless already diagonal). Do you mean $A=PDP^{-1}$ where $D$ is complex? Then $P$ cannot be real, and I do not understand what you mean by $P\in {\mathfrak so}(2)$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan 
Maybe I am a little confused and apologize for that. What I really want is to prove that the function $\exp:\mathfrak{so}(2)\to SO(2)$ is surjective and I thought this result would help me

Comment: If this is all what you are after, then the answer is positive. In fact, whenever $G$ is a compact connected Lie group, its  exponential map is surjective.

Comment: @MoisheKohan 
the fact is that I need $A=PDP^{-1}$ with $D=\begin{bmatrix} e^{i\theta}& 0\\ 0 & e^{-i\theta}\end{bmatrix}$ to conclude that $e^B=A$, where $B=P\begin{bmatrix} i\theta& 0\\ 0 & -i\theta\end{bmatrix}P^{-1}$ but I don't know if $D$ has the form $D=\begin{bmatrix} e^{i\theta}& 0\\ 0 & e^{-i\theta}\end{bmatrix}$, is this true?

Comment: Besides what @MoisheKohan points out, you should clarify if you work over real or complex numbers. Also, my definition of $\mathfrak{so}(2)$ is $\lbrace \pmatrix{0&x\\-x&0}: x\in \mathbb R \rbrace$, and I wonder if we agree on that (and why it features here)?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg 
I am working on real numbers and their definition of $\mathfrak{so}(2)$ matches mine.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg 
How can I use all this then to prove that $exp:\mathfrak{so}(2)\to SO(2)$ is surjective?

Comment: If your goal is just to prove the exponential is surjective, you can prove that very easily by just direct computation.  Do you know what an arbitrary element of $SO(2)$ looks like?

Comment: @EricWofsey 
I know that every element in $SO(2)$ has the form $\begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta)& -\sin(\theta)\\ \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}$ for some $\theta\in (0,2\pi)$, could I use here that $SO(2)\cong\mathbb{S}^1$?

Comment: Do you know how the exponential map is defined here? Just use the definition and you'll see a nice application of Euler's formula.

Answer (score 2):

$A$ being in $SO(2)$ means (among other things) that the determinant of $A$ is one, so that the *product* of the eigenvalues of $A$ (which form the non-zero entries of $D$) equals 1. $D$ being in $\mathfrak{so}(2)$ means that the trace of $D$ is zero, which means that the *sum* of the eigenvalues equals zero.

Intuitively it is clear that the condition that two numbers multiply to 1 does *not* imply that their sum is zero, so it remains to find a counterexample.

How about rotation over 45 degrees? The corresponding matrix $A$ satisfies $A^8 = I$ so both entries of $D$ must satisfy $\lambda^8 = 1$. This equation has 8 solutions, but the two solutions $\lambda = \frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $\lambda = \frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}$ are more interesting as they do not satisfy $\lambda^n = 1$ for any $n < 8$.

My intuition tells me that these two special solutions are the eigenvalues, but leave checking that to you. If this is correct their sum is $\sqrt{2}$ and not 0.

Comment: Sorry but I just edited the question, I don't really care if $D\in \mathfrak{so}(2)$, what I want to know is if $P\in \mathfrak{so}(2)$

Comment: With this, I intend to prove that $\exp:\mathfrak{so}(2)\to SO(2)$ is surjective, but I don't know what form $D$ has

Comment: Is $D$ of the form $D=\begin{bmatrix} e^{i\theta}& 0\\ 0 & e^{-i\theta}\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: Ok, first off: yes the exponential map is surjective here. Geometrically speaking $SO(2)$ looks like a circle, $\mathfrak{so}(2)$ looks like a line, the exponential map just wraps the line around the circle. We can make the previous statement even a little more explicit: $SO(2)$ is isomorphic to the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathfrak{so(2)}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ and in this picture the exponential map is the map that sends $x \in \mathbb{R}$ to $e^{ix}$.

Comment: Now if you want to describe the same thing in terms of matrices you need to find the isomorphism of $SO(2)$ to the unit circle and your diagonalization argument is one way to do that. So far so good! However the question to which group the element $P$ belongs is not very relevant for that, for all we know and care it lives in the much much bigger group $GL(2, \mathbb{C})$.